# javascript RFC 3986 implementation?

Tags: javascript, regex, rfc

Is there already a javascript function/library/snippet written for the validation of the RFC 1738 URL specifications listed at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt?

Comment: how is this off-topic? this site is getting ridiculous

Comment: WTF ? This is TOTALLY ON TOPIC !!!

Comment: It's still relevant today.

Answer (score 5):

From https://github.com/googlearchive/caja/blob/f94fa2df4343b8aee01c22b5094fe048fd22af30/src/com/google/caja/plugin/uri.js

> Implements RFC 3986 for parsing/formatting URIs.

You can find usage examples in the [unit tests](https://github.com/googlearchive/caja/blob/f94fa2df4343b8aee01c22b5094fe048fd22af30/tests/com/google/caja/plugin/uri_test.js).

Answer (score 4):

No, but I've written an article that covers the related RFC-3986 (which updates 1738):

[Regular Expression URI Validation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html)

I've set up the article so that you can double-click on any of the regexes to get a correctly formatted snippet for a variety of languages.

Comment: i mean yes you've provided the regex for each part but how do i combine them to form the full thing?

Comment: @Tingting: The regexes towards the end of the article (i.e. `absolute-URI`, `URI` and `relative-ref`) _do_ validate a complete URI. However, these do not validate that the domain is valid with respect to the DNS naming convention. I've written a function in PHP to validate absolute HTTP/FTP URLs. You can see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191720/regular-expression-to-match-generic-url/6202972#6202972). I have not created a javascript version yet.