# Why regex is reacting on 5-n www?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have such regex:

```
/^(?!((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?))/
```

When I type: 
`www.test.com` - it doesn't find anything (as should be)

When I type:
`aaaaa` - it's valid (it's true)

But why when I type:

`wwwww` - I get invalid regex? (I mean it doesn't match regex)

What am I doing wrong in my regex?

Comment: Paste it into regex101.com and debug.

Comment: It's a negative lookahead `(?!` that among other stuff doesn't want to find something that starts with www.  Indeed, debug and perhaps try to simplify that long regex.  The regexr.com site has a nice reference.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how can i debug it? what do you mean?

Comment: This question is of the type What does this regex mean. The answer is the same: paste the test string to the input field and regex to the regex field at regex101.com (or use Expresso for .NET regex testing) and read the description. Then delete all but one subpatterns to see how the regex behaves. Add the x modifier to insert newlines into the pattern and indent it to better see what groups you have. Test, test, test.

Comment: regex101.com -- awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to escape the period after `www`. Try replacing `www.` with `www\.`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to build a URI regex. I can link a good-enough version here (I don't use this one but it might work for you):

```
/^(?:(\w[\w\d+.-]+):\/\/)?(?:(.+?):(.+)@)?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|[^#:\/\?\s]+)(?::(\d+))?\/?(\/(?:[^#\/\?\s]+\/)*[^#\/\?\s]+\/?)?(?:\?((?:[^#=\/\s]+=[^&;#\/\s]+[&;]?)+))?(?:#(.+))?$/g
```

http://regexr.com/3cmin

But I suggest you have a look at these
https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html

[Regular expression to match generic URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191720/regular-expression-to-match-generic-url)

The official standard for URIs is [RFC-3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

Otherwise just use [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com) to debug your regex and [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) to explore it.

As was mentioned above you did not escape the . after www. Also your regex is infinite because it can match zero characters. You need to put a $ at the end at least to indicate end of match. And you are turning your regex into a lookahead right off the bat.